# sharepoint Workflow works differently in 2010 & 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have List 1 which has 2 workflows. Created workflow in 2010

Workflow 1 triggers when item created

Workflow 2 triggers when item changed

Workflow 1 copies list 1 item to another list, send email & updates a field in List 1.

The issue i am facing, when an item is created Workflow 1 is triggered and because i am updating a field in List 1, workflow 2 is getting triggered. I don't want the workflow 2 to run when i am updating an item in list when creating an item

But when i create the same workflows in 2013 it works fine.Workflow 2 does not get triggered when creating an item.But cannot use 2013 workflow as it does not copy attachment from one list to another

i want to update the status in list 1 to "Sent".But don't want the change item Workflow 2 to trigger.

Any help suggestion?

Comment: What are you updating? Is it something arbitrary that you can't just set it when creating?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to add a hidden checkbox.

This can be done by turning on "Allow Content Type Management"

In the browser, go to the advanced settings screen for list 2. Turn on "Manage Content Types." Then Editing the default Content type in that list (the first one under content types on the list main settings page). Next add field to content type. Select "Yes/No" set default to No then save. Next go to the advanced settings for that field and set it to Hidden.

In Designer edit workflow 2. Add a stage to the beginning of the workflow that checks the newly created field. i.e.

```
if isSent is equal to No
End the workflow
```